# How can i style the form errors of the USerCreationForm in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

I m working on a project i have made a registration form by using USerCreationForm , I want to style the form errors cause the errors look very ugly in my template [image of my form and how error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRQEi.png)

So what i want is that it shouldn't display that of which field the error is it should directly display the error.

My registration form

```
<form action="{% url 'registration_pg' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="name-container">
                <!-- < id="first_name " class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="first name" required> -->
                {{form.first_name}}
                {{form.last_name}}
            </div>
            <div class="username-container form-inputs">
                {{form.username}}
            </div>
            <div class="student-info">
                {{form.std}}
                {{form.div}}
                {{form.rollno}}
            </div>
            <div class="user-fields">
                {{form.email}}
                {{form.password1}}
                {{form.password2}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-errors">
                {{form.errors}}
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-info ripple-effect" type="submit" name="Submit" alt="sign in" style="background:#0277bd;">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

My forms.py file

```
class StudentCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'first_name', 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'first name'}))
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'last_name', 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'last name'}))
username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'username', 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'username eg (jhon16)'}))
std = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'id': 'std', 'class': 'form-control stu-info', 'placeholder': 'std'}))
div = forms.CharField(max_length=1, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'div', 'class': 'form-control stu-info', 'placeholder': 'division'}))
rollno = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'id': 'rollno', 'class': 'form-control stu-info', 'placeholder': 'roll no'}))
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'id': 'email', 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'email'}))
password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'id': 'password1', 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'password'}))
password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'id': 'password2', 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'confirm password'}))

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'std', 'div', 'rollno', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same issue but I've found the solution.

```
        {% for field, error in form.errors.items %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger my-3 p-1" role="alert">
            {{ error|striptags }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

First, you have to use a for loop to have access to each field and its error message. Then insert only the variable error and apply the striptags (It'll remove the bullet point).